# What caused this character's trauma?

Tags: wonder-egg-priority

(Forgive the awkward wording, but I'm trying to be as un-spoilery as I can.)

In Episode 12 of *Wonder Egg Priority*, Ai hatches a Wonder Egg containing

> herself from a parallel universe.

This girl's Wonder Killer takes the form of

> Sawaki-sensei.

This suggests he did something that traumatised the girl and helped drive her to suicide, but it's never stated what. Furthermore, Ai spends the entire fight insistent that the Wonder Killer is based on her own cognition of that person, and not what they are actually like.

What did he do to her? And if he didn't do anything, then why was he her Wonder Killer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on my own memory and understanding of the episode, YMMV.)

It's strongly hinted in the flashbacks and lines dropped by both the other Ai and her Wonder Killer that many key events *other* than getting involved with the Wonder Eggs still happened, in particular:

- Ai developed a crush on Sawaki-sensei;
- Koito Nagase killed herself after having some kind of involvement with Sawaki-sensei;
- Sawaki-sensei became romantically involved with Ai's mother, and they discussed getting married.

As a result, that universe's Ai suspected that Sawaki-sensei was somehow involved in Koito's death, and that he was using Ai's mother as a means to get to Ai, possibly to molest her. This is why she developed an image of him in her head as a monster.

Note that the main Ai *also* had these same suspicions, but because she had formed friendships with the other girls (one of whom was related to Sawaki-sensei) *and* had confronted her fears and anxieties about Sawaki-sensei (and confronted him about it), *and* had learned more about the nature of the Wonder Killers from her experiences and from Ura-Acca's backstory, she was better able to dismiss her paranoia about Sawaki-sensei.

Comment: There's no indication that Koito even existed in the alternate world: alternate Ai repeatedly states that she's never heard of her, much less met her. The other two points make sense, though.

Comment: Argh, you're probably right. I am working off memory here, so it's then reasonable to assume that Sawaki's attention just went straight to Ai.